# API documentation for VS Code commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for *official* API documentation for various VS Code commands when used as extension points. For example, if I'm building a plugin that will call `git.clone` e.g. `vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.clone', someGitRepoUrl);`

I want to know what the response will be or what additional parameters are involved. Is the expectation just that I should brute force debug this command or is there any actual documentation available?

I've already been to http://code.visualstudio.com and found nothing useful. Certainly the purported documentation pages [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) weren't helpful.  Or is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: I'm noticing two "resource recommendation" close-votes. This question is on-topic, and as far as I can see, is looking for official documentation. There is a useful and on-topic problem this question is looking for a solution for. I do not see how it will attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. The `git.clone` was intended only as an example.

Comment: just to hammer in the point that asking for official resources is generally okay, to prevent further wrong-reason close-votes, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/11107541.

Comment: @user I wish there were more users with common sense like you.

Comment: @CodeCaster part of it has been hammered into me by Cody. Trust me. I've made my fair share of past bad close-votes when I got my privileges and was overenthusiastic about "helping out".

Answer (score 2):

#### The docs seem to be out of date right now

Part of me is suspected that the documentation in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands is just really out of date / incomplete. (The source can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/api/references/commands.md)). And indeed, if you [search "`is:issue is:open commands`" in the issues tab of the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+commands), at the time of this writing, the top search result is [Documentation for Built-in Commands may be out of date #6029](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/6029).

You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for its prioritization, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy "+1" / "bump" comments. You are very very welcome to submit Pull Requests offering help to add docs!

There's also *another* command API page that is also incomplete: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands/. I'm not sure why they have two pages.

#### Workaround 1: Read the source code

One option (and I'm sorry for suggesting this, since I know reading source code is not something that everyone is comfortable with) is to just read the source code. Open https://github.dev/microsoft/vscode, open the Search View, and search for the command ID of the command you're interested in, and then trace to code to where the command gets registered.

For example, search `'editor.actions.findWithArgs'`, which will lead to a `StartFindWithArgs`. If you the search for `StartFindWithArgs`, you'll find a `StartFindWithArgsAction` class, where in its `run` method, it has an `args` parameter of type `IFindStartArguments`, which if you go to the definition, shows the type definition of the command's arguments.

#### Workaround 2: Use the keybindings `"args"` property's suggestions

Disclaimer: this will only get you an idea of the command's arguments- not its return value.

One thing you can try is opening your keybindings.json file (`Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in command palette) and then creating a new keybinding entry, entering the command, creating the `"args"` property, and then triggering suggestions. Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "",
    "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
    "args": {
        // <- put caret here and trigger suggestions
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works for all commands that accept arguments (it doesn't seem to for the documented commands that begin with "`vscode.`"), but it does for some others, such as `editor.actions.findWithArgs`, `cursorMove`, and a bunch of others that I tried from the documentation page.

Comment: Oh, I read through the source code alright and it only filled me with deeper frustration that something like this came out of MS.  

Ex:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9f081fd11a036678d0453c5820554c27dc39173e/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L757 tells me nothing about what `options` I can provide and no indication of success/failure and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9f081fd11a036678d0453c5820554c27dc39173e/extensions/git/src/git.ts#L414 returns `Promise<string>` but you'd have to read the entire fn to find out the string is the folder path. If it's successful I guess?

Comment: It's enough to almost make a guy appreciate hungarian notation.  Almost.

If you're a new dev: Please document your code! Even if it seems trivial, 2 minute of doc's can collectively save hundreds of developer hours later on.